# Can I organise CSS by their tags, and not have all of them seperate?

Tags: html, css

To explain what I wish to achieve, lets say I have a long css document with many classes. I have several different "h1" tags and "h2" tags, "iframe", "ul", and many have different classes. Is it possible for all "h1" or other tags, regardless of class, to be grouped together and all "iframe" are grouped together in one group in Notepad++.

```css
h1.left {
 font-family: Papyrus;
 font-size: 45px;
 color: white;
 margin-left: 15px;
}
h1.center {
 font-family: Papyrus;
 font-size: 30px;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <pre>PS: All code in this document is just
       so it would be seen as I meant it to be,
        and I hope you can read it right.<pre>
  <!--For example:-->
  + h1
  <!--And if i roll the h1 down, i can get all h1 in the document:-->
  <ul>
     <li> h1.left</li>
     <li>h1.center <li>
     <li>h1.right<li>
  <!--And if i open those again, I will get all the code that is inside them-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you want the tags to be grouped? In the css file?

Comment: I think what he means is to have kind of a styleguide generated

Comment: In Notepad++, if language is given, you can hide the code and only see the tag. What I want is that all with the same tag, even if they have different classes, can be put into one group so i dont have to make a document with many single tags. And if i need to edit or make a new of a certain tag, i go into the main group and add it there.

Comment: dont think there a collapse/expand of all css

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether Notepad++ can run SASS but it sounds like what you are after.

```
h1 {
    color: white;
    font-family: Papyrus;
    text-align: center;

    &.left {
        font-size: 45px;
    }
    &.center {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
}
```